# How can I call my API stored in appsettings.json in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What I have learned is better store the sensitive data inside `appSettings.json` in .NET Core. I have an API address which I need to consume in my application, how should I store and call it from the `appSettings.json`? Can I store it as shown here?

```
"MyApi": {
    "API": "http://example.com"
}
```

If I want to call it, how can I access it? If I don't want to use this approach, I should call it directly through `HttpClient`:

```
var client = newHttpClient()
client.BaseAddress = newUri("http://example.com");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
public class MyClass
{
         private readonly string _myApi;

        public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
             myApi= configuration["MyApi:API"]);
        }
}
```

after this you can use url anywhere inside of the class

But I highly recommend you to use an IHttpClientFactory

```
  private readonly string _myApi;
  private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
 {
       _myApi= configuration["MyApi:API"]);
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
}

public async Task Get ()
{
  var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
 ......
}
```

Comment: thanks and how should i get error because if IConfiguration ,where should i write it inside startup?

Comment: @masali You don't need   to use any startup in this case. Put this code inside  the class you are using  to send the http request.

Answer (score 0):

you have some way.

1- you can add httpClient in first step on start application and in controller or your services inject it with httpFactory

> Startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
              Configuration = configuration;
        }

         public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

         public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
         {
             services.AddHttpClient("myApi", options =>
             {
               options.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["MyApi:API"]);
              });

            //....

         }
    }
```

> Controller or Your class

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private  HttpClient apiClient;

    public HomeController( IHttpClientFactory factory )
    {
        apiClient = factory.CreateClient("myApi");
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        var resoult = await apiClient.GetAsync("/people/id/10");

        //process your result

        return View();
    }
}
```

Update :

2 - inject Configuration to your controller or services like

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress =new Uri(_configuration["MyApi:API"]);
        var resoult = await httpClient.GetAsync("/people/id/10");

        //process your result

        return View();
    }
}
```